# Generate text with DOM with less code

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on an application that's printing out some text to the user in HTML with DOM. Below you can see my code and I have some questions regarding it.

1. Is there another way to create the text below with DOM (without using `innerHTML`) that needs less code?
2. What is the best way of making the text bold, eg. "Firstname" (just the text, not the content in the variable)?

Here is my JS:

```
header.appendChild(headertext);
p.appendChild(header);

var p2 = document.createElement('p');

var br = document.createElement('br');
var text1 = document.createTextNode("Firstname: " + firstname);
p2.appendChild(text1);
p2.appendChild(br);

var br2 = document.createElement('br');     
var text2 = document.createTextNode("Lastname: " + lastname);
p2.appendChild(text2);
p2.appendChild(br2);

var br3 = document.createElement('br');
var text3 = document.createTextNode("Zip code: " + zipcode);
p2.appendChild(text3);
p2.appendChild(br3);

var br = document.createElement('br');
var text4 = document.createTextNode("Phone nr: " + phonenr);
p2.appendChild(text4);
p2.appendChild(br);

square.appendChild(p);
square.appendChild(p2);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor this

```
var br2 = document.createElement('br');     
var text2 = document.createTextNode("Lastname: " + lastname);
p2.appendChild(text2);
p2.appendChild(br2);
```

into a helper function:

```
function appendTextNode(tagToAppend, textValue){
    var br2 = document.createElement('br');     
    var text2 = document.createTextNode(textValue);
    tagToAppend.appendChild(text2);
    tagToAppend.appendChild(br2);
}
```

And then:

```
var p2 = document.createElement('p');

appendTextNode(p2, "Firstname: " + firstname);
appendTextNode(p2, "Lastname: " + lastname);
appendTextNode(p2, "Zip code: " + zipcode);
appendTextNode(p2, "Phone nr: " + phonenr);
```

To answer your second question, to make this text bold, I would create the content like the below

(I know you mentioned not using innerHTML, but I interpreted that as not wanting to use innerHTML in order to dump large, pre-formed html chunks in)

```
var text2 = document.createElement('span');
text2.innerHTML = textValue;
text2.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
tagToAppend.appendChild(text2);
```

Comment: Why the heck would you use `.innerHTML` for text content. That's stupid. You may also want to favour a `<b>` or `<strong>` tag rather then `<span>` or use a `class` rather then `.style.fontWeight`

Comment: @Raynos - I'm no expert in creating dom elements in script.  What would you use for simple text content?  I remember innerTEXT being IE specific or something.

Comment: Generally you would use `.textContent`. legacy browsers support can be manually done by feature detecting for `.textContent` or `.innerText` or using a dom shim

Comment: I thought we were using templates or data binding instead of this crap

Comment: @Raynos - what would be the benefit of doing feature detection rather than just using innerHTML, which is supported everywhere.

Comment: @Raynos nothing but why write those "helper" functions every time manually when you can write a templating engine in 15 mins and have it done automatically

Comment: @AdamRackis because a) it's stupid. b) it's the wrong tool. c) it's a massive overhead. d) it promotes passing in html strings into the function when you only want textual strings e) it's a dirty hack f) it's simply bad code and g) you should use `.textContent` because that's the correct and future proof way to set text on a `Node`. One should not confuse DOM code with DOM code that works in n browser environments. No where in the answer did he mention how he will handle broken DOM environments.

Comment: @Esailija because templating engines are ugly. I personally don't like them

Comment: @Esailija - this is clearly some guys homework.  He's clearly just learning.  Wouldn't you agree that building a template engine might be a bit advanced at this point?

Comment: @Raynos - same comment.  This is homework.  He's trying to learn this stuff from scratch.  Feature detection / dom shimming - don't you think that's a bit advanced for a learner like this?

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes it is, so use `.textContent` and don't support legacy browsers. Otherwise teach him how to support older browsers with valid techniques. Don't teach him bad practices. Especially if it's homework, tell him how to do it correctly

Comment: @AdamRackis, sorry I missed the homework tag :D my point still stands for the question `Is there another way to create the text below with DOM (without using innerHTML) that needs less code?` as a general answer in case someone else is having this problem as well

Comment: +1 for your reusable function approach, but @Raynos makes some valid points. `.innerHTML` is tempting because of its convenience (in compatibility), but it isn't really a pure approach.

Comment: @Esailija - I'm sure glad this *is* homework.  I'd hate to think someone was writing production code like this!  So many good libraries out there to handle tedium like this :)  But yeah, I just want to give this student a **simple** bump, and hopefully he'll get sufficiently excited about development that in a few years he'll be using jQuery, doing feature detection, using template libraries like  knockout, etc etc

Comment: @RightSaidFred - fair enough.  Next time I'll be more specific about things that aren't too standard.

Comment: ...that said, in the real world, I'd side with practicality over purity in plenty of circumstances.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - you've given me hope for the world, I was beginning to think I was the only one...

Comment: @RightSaidFred Corporate sell out! Why you no stick to ideals. Seriously though in the real world you use a browser normalization utility of choice :\

Answer (score 1):

You would use a templating engine like so:

```
<script type="text/x-some-random-templating-engine" id="address-template">
    <p>
        Firstname: <?= firstname ?><br>
        Lastname: <?= lastname ?><br>
        Zip code: <?= zipcode ?><br>
        Phone nr: <?= phonenr ?><br>
    </p>
</script>
```

Then:

```
document.body.appendChild( RandomTemplatingEngine.parse( "address-template" ).evaluate({
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    zipcode: 12345,
    phonenr: 123456789
    })
);
```

You can either create a templating engine yourself or find one on the [internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+microtemplate) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_templates)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate way of shortening the main code a bit:

```
p.appendChild(header).appendChild(headertext);

var p2 = document.createElement('p'),
    data = [ "Firstname: " + firstname,
             "Lastname: " + lastname,
             "Zip code: " + zipcode,
             "Phone nr: " + phonenr ],
    len = data.length;

while( len-- ) {
    p2.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data[len] ) );
    p2.appendChild( document.createElement( 'br' ) );
}
square.appendChild(p);
square.appendChild(p2);
```

---

To style the first word, wrap it in the element of your choice. Doesn't require that much more than the code above:

```
p.appendChild(header).appendChild(headertext);

var p2 = document.createElement('p'),
    data = [ ["Firstname: ", firstname],
             ["Lastname: ", lastname],
             ["Zip code: ", zipcode],
             ["Phone nr: ", phonenr] ],
    len = data.length;

while( len-- ) {
    p2.appendChild( document.createElement( 'strong' ) )
      .appendChild( document.createTextNode( data[len][0] ) );
    p2.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data[len][1] ) );
    p2.appendChild( document.createElement( 'br' ) );
}
square.appendChild(p);
square.appendChild(p2);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p2EUp/)**